# Tool to search a call to Type.Method?

Tags: c#, .net

This may be a wild dream but is there a way I can say search all of my code and if you see a variable with the type TYPE and it calls THISMETHOD add it to a list of results. The method is a common name and the variables can be called anything (like a single letter) so its pretty difficult to search. I'm doing a search for TYPE and looking at its scope for the method which is slightly painful

Comment: "All of my code" -> Are you talking about all code in a solution or all code on your hard disk?

Comment: can't you just right-click the method and select "Find All References"?

Comment: @DiskJunky: Wow I didn't realize. I'll accept if you make that an answer. I forgot that since I been building via command line for a while now and don't have a proper solution

Comment: @BruteCode added as requested :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the method in Visual Studio and select "Find All References". Should sort you out :-)